# Overriding CSS in AllItems.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I want to add some CSS in my site. I read on others questions that it's better to override CSS. I'm OK with that ([Tutorial here](https://sharepointbrandingauthority.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/overriding-core-css-files/)).

But, I browsed every folder of my site in SharePoint Designer and I have not seen a .css file, not even the corev4.css.

So my question is : where can I create and override a CSS file for the AllItems.aspx page ? I want to modify all the entire page, like the ribbon and the menu to make a new site.

From [this documentation by MS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-a-custom-style-sheet-to-a-SharePoint-site-97fe83a2-b435-4f27-8747-db041d4c2d8e), I cannot find the _styles folder.

NB: I specify that I'm not the Central Administrator and this is SharePoint 2010.

Comment: No need to tinker in SPD. Just add a content editor webpart to the page, upload all your css in a text file to a library in the same site and link them together.

Comment: Can you detail please? I don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

To add some CSS in the site, you do not need to override the CSS file.

About how to add CSS to SharePoint, you can refer the following article, which may be useful to you.

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.jp/2012/05/adding-javascript-and-css-to-sharepoint.html

By the way, the corev4.css is in the “v4.master” master page.

[image]

Comment: I already visited this page, that's not what I'm looking for. In fact I want to add css to modify the entire page, like the lists or the ribbon